# Approach for monitoring internet backbone traffic volume

Tags: internet, network-monitoring, traffic

I'm interested in getting a picture of relative volume across different internet backbones. In particular, I'd like to see how traffic volume over a given route differs over the course of a day or from one day to the next.

[InternetTrafficReport.com](http://www.internettrafficreport.com/) is the closest approximation to this that I've found online, and their approach is to test ping times to a number of key routers from several geographically-dispersed servers. This sounds like one straightforward way to measure, but I don't have several geographically-dispersed servers.

Is there a different approach for sampling this type of information from a single server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about reporting for *your* pipes the best suggestion I can offer is to configure your edge routers to generate netflow exports and use a flow cruncher ([flow-tools](http://www.splintered.net/sw/flow-tools/) & [JKFlow](http://jkflow.sourceforge.net/) or something commercial) to turn it into something easily-readable.

If you're talking about getting providers to tell you what the load is on their various links I'm not sure who you would have to bribe to go about getting that info: In my experience it's usually considered "internal data" not for general/public distribution (though having been privy to flow data at a tier-2 provider I can tell you that watching the data can be interesting :)

**Edit to add:** If you're not interested in your provider specifically bur rather more general data CAIDA ([www.caida.org](http://www.caida.org/)) has a few real-time traffic monitoring stations & nice breakdowns.  I wouldn't call the data comprehensive, but it's pretty good.

Comment: No, I am specifically looking for major internet backbones - nothing I control directly. The essence of my question is something like "Is Japan experiencing unusually high internet traffic right now?"

Comment: No method I know of to monitor the actual traffic -- Like I mentioned that kind of data is usually closely guarded, and the size of the data set (can be upwards of a gig an hour of just flow summaries) precludes pushing it to external aggregators in anything resembling real-time.  Someone else may come up with another option though.

Comment: Thanks, if it's not available, then it's not available. The CAIDA link is helpful.